# Why are my colors separated/shifted when using obs/v4l2sink/v4l2loopback?

Tags: video, video-encoding, v4l, v4l2loopback

Im using OBS with v4l2sink and v4l2loopback to edit my video for a remote trainig.
The preview in obs looks fine, but the video has some serious color shifts in any tool I try to display the v4l2loopack I'm directing the sink to.

View from OBS:
[image: View from OBS]

View from Browser:
[image: View from Browser]
You can see that all colors have a green shadow about half the grid width.
Is there any setting that I could change to fix this?
The video format selected in the V4l2sinkProperties is YUV420 as all others result in "format not supported"

I run Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64). OBS Studio is 25.0.8 installed via apt. obs-v4l2sink and v4lsloopback are built and installed from the current GitHub sources.

Comment: i just checked and i cannot reproduce this here; with `v4l2loopback`-0.12.5 (as shipped by Debian/bullseye), *OBS Music Edition* (25.0.7) with `obs-v4l2sink`-0.1.0, and Firefox-78.5.0 on https://webcamtests.com/; both with `YUV420` and `YUY2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling everything, it works fine for me now. So I have no idea which setting I fiddled with to create this problem :/